# CharAt index error while reading through text file in Java

Tags: java, indexof, charat

I'm getting some confusing errors when I iterate through this entire enable1 txt file (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dolph/dictionary/master/enable1.txt) to check if it meets the "I before E except after C" English word 'rule'. I noticed the code succeeds when I remove the "-1" from charAt(indexEI - 1) that I starred below (****).

Any ideas why this might be? The errors just say "at java.lang.String.charAt (String.java: 658)", "Main.ibeforeE", and "at Main.main" in seemingly random spots in the "e" section of the iteration. Then it says var\cache\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED at the very end.

I'm quite new to Java so any other constructive criticism is appreciated as well. Thanks!

Main:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    EnableWord test = new EnableWord();
    test.EnableWords();


    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list = test.getList();


    int x = 0;
    int falseCounter = 0;

    while (x < list.size()) {
        System.out.print(list.get(x) + ": ");

        String input = list.get(x);

        if (input.equals("x")) {
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println(iBeforeE(input));
                if(!iBeforeE(input)) {
                    falseCounter++;
                }
            x++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(falseCounter);
}

public static boolean iBeforeE(String input) {


    if (!input.contains("ie") && !input.contains("ei")) {
        return true;
    }

    if (input.contains("ie")) {
        int indexIE = input.indexOf("ie");
        Character searchIE = input.charAt(indexIE - 1);
        if (!searchIE.toString().equals("c")) {
            return true;
        }

    } else if (input.contains("ei")) {
        int indexEI = input.indexOf("ei");
        ****Character searchEI = input.charAt(indexEI - 1);****
        if (searchEI.toString().equals("c")) {
            return true;
        }
    }


    return false;

}
```

Class  EnableWord:

```
}


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class EnableWord {

private ArrayList<String> list;
private Scanner s;
private File file;

public EnableWord() {
}

public void EnableWords() {

    try {
        this.s = new Scanner(this.file = new File("enable1.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EnableWord.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    this.list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        list.add(s.next());
    }
    s.close();

}

public void printWords() {

    for (String word : list) {
        System.out.println(word);
    }

}

public ArrayList<String> getList() {

    ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String word : list) {
        newList.add(word);

    }
    return list;
}

}
```

Comment: There should be one line above the "at java.lang.String.charAt..." in the error message. Please [edit] your post to include this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are words in your list that start with ei (ex: eicosanoid)
When your program gets to these words, it finds the index of 'ei' to be 0.  So the value of "indexEI - 1" is negative 1, an invalid index.

you could fix it by checking if indexEI is > 0 before trying to check the previous character is a 'c':

```
if (indexEI == 0 || input.charAt(indexEI - 1).toString().equals("c")) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Ah I should have known! Thank you so much!

Comment: Your file doesn't have any words that start with 'ie', but it would be good to use the same logic in  the 'ie' block as well, or better yet extract that logic to a method:

Answer (score 0):

As soon as a word starts with 'ie' or 'ei' then `input.charAt(indexIE - 1)` will generate an error since `indexIE` then is 0.

I am not sure what you want to do in your code but some kind of check is needed

```
if (indexIE == 0) {

} else {
    //current code
}
```